# Mongoose updateOne() stops working. No errors thrown

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Hello and thank you for taking a look at this.

I have a scheduled function that contacts an API and is supposed to save the data to a local DB. It works several times and then stops saving. I have confirmed that the functions are executing per their scheduled times. Mongoose does not save the data and does not give me an error.

2 part request:

- I would love help trying to catch and log the error.
  -Maybe my logger(s) are in the wrong location?
- Also, if you have any insight as to why it works when I start the
  server and then eventually stops working that would be appreciated as
  well.
  -Maybe I am not 'returning' the functions properly?

**Get the data from the API:**

```
function updateWeather(){
    const weatherurl = 'https://api.aerisapi.com/observations/pendleton,or?&format=json&filter=allstations&limit=1&client_id=bRZUxQc8j4z41CrH7SM6u&client_secret=GaEA7lMyLKnQwRsUcxv1mnNhTUkx6KUtVsrIXVcR';

axios.get(weatherurl)
    .then(response=>{

        // console.log(response.data);
          let condition     = response.data.response.ob.weather,
                temp        = response.data.response.ob.tempF,
                windDir     = response.data.response.ob.windDir,
                windSpd     = response.data.response.ob.windSpeedMPH,
                windGust    = response.data.response.ob.windGustMPH,
                windChill   = response.data.response.ob.windchillF,
                humidity    = response.data.response.ob.humidity,
                icon        = response.data.response.ob.icon,
                date        = moment().utcOffset(-8).format('YYYY-MM-DD'),
                updated     = moment().utcOffset(-8).format('MM/DD/YY HH:mm');

                if(temp <= 35){
                    var tempIcon = 'https://cdn.aerisapi.com/wxicons/v2/cold.png';
                }else if(temp >= 80){
                    var tempIcon =  'https://cdn.aerisapi.com/wxicons/v2/hot.png';
                }else{
                    var tempIcon = '';
                }

                currentWeather.push({date:date, condition:condition, temp:temp, windChill:windChill, windDir:windDir, windSpd:windSpd, windGust:windGust, humidity:humidity, icon:icon, tempIcon:tempIcon, updated:updated});

        return currentWeather[0]
    }).then(currentWeather=>{
        // console.log(currentWeather);
        saveWeather(currentWeather);
    }).catch(error=>{
        logger.error(error);
    });
    return currentWeather;
}
```

**Save data to DB:**

```
function saveWeather(weather){
    logger.info('saveWeather connection status: '+mongoose.connection.readyState);
    if(mongoose.connection.readyState !== 1){
        mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/fdData", {useNewUrlParser: true});
    }
    Weather.updateOne({date: weather.date}, {date:weather.date, condition:weather.condition, temp:weather.temp, windChill:weather.windChill, windDir:weather.windDir, windSpd:weather.windSpd, windGust:weather.windGust, humidity:weather.humidity, icon:weather.icon, tempIcon:weather.tempIcon, updated:weather.updated}, {upsert:true}, error=> {

        if (error){
            logger.error(error);
        } else{
            logger.info('Weather Saved to DB')
        }
    })
    return weather;
}
```

Thanks again!

-Adam

Comment: Have you attempted logging at both updateWeather and in the first .then() before returning currentWeather? This may provide some insight. I also see that you are not closing the connection to your db which may cause some weird behavior.

Comment: Yes and you could also try to catch any connection errors to the db by adding a catch block on the `mongoose.connect` method to check if something is going on there...

Comment: Sample gist here on logging your MongoDB (dis)connections: https://gist.githubusercontent.com/pasupulaphani/9463004/raw/beca4ad9d31e5c6d77f3bbaabe99043e63570550/mongoose_connet.js

Comment: Now we have an error!

"server instance pool was destroyed"

from what I can tell this means the connection closed and needs re-opened?

Comment: I believe I have figured it out. I was calling a connection in each of my modules instead of just in my app.js. I have removed the extra connections. I will let you know if it solves the actual issue.